# Determining if a process is information preserving in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, information, unitarity

I was wondering if one is provided with two quantum states such that one is the evolution of another through some unknown process, is it possible to determine if the aforementioned process is information preserving. To put it more concretely, let's say we have the following initial state, $|\Phi\rangle_{initial}=\alpha\left|\Phi_{0}\right\rangle+\beta\left|\Phi_{1}\right\rangle$, and the final state is as follows $|\Phi\rangle_{final} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|\Phi_{0}\right\rangle\left|\Psi_{1}\right\rangle+\left|\Phi_{1}\right\rangle\left|\Psi_{0}\right\rangle\right) \otimes\left(\alpha\left|\chi_{0}\right\rangle+\beta\left|\chi_1\right\rangle\right)$ i.e., we have the following scenario:

$\alpha\left|\Phi_{0}\right\rangle+\beta\left|\Phi_{1}\right\rangle \xrightarrow{Unknown\,Process} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|\Phi_{0}\right\rangle\left|\Psi_{1}\right\rangle+\left|\Phi_{1}\right\rangle\left|\chi_{1}\right\rangle\right) \otimes\left(\alpha\left|\chi_{0}\right\rangle+\beta\left|\Psi_0\right\rangle\right)$.

Is it possible to determine if the process preserves the information of the initial state? Any insight or references is very much appreciated.

Comment: generally speaking, a map is "information preserving" if it is unitary. One way to see this is to observe that the only invertible quantum channels are unitary channels. Given two states, they are connected by a unitary channel iff they (or rather, their density matrix representations) have the same eigenvalues. Any two pure states are connected by a unitary channel